# US Magazine forwarding

Tags: usa

In the US, you can get a vogue subscription for $15 (for the first year). Internationally, where I am, it's $70. This made me wonder if there's some independent service to have the Vogue automatically forwarded from the US for less than $55 a year. Does anyone know of such a service?

Comment: $55/year in shipping costs for how many issues per year?  I don't think that's going to work out economically.  The difference between $70 and $15 is probably shipping/admin costs and not a significant source of profit for the publisher.  In fact, only $55/year extra sounds like a great deal; I've been quoted much larger differences for foreign subscriptions on paper, and switched all international subscriptions to digital-only for that reason.